# Printing records on paper using ms access buttons

Tags: vba, ms-access

My question is sounds simple:
I want to print some query using button in ms access form.

Example:

```
Private Sub Print_Click()

    sqls = " SELECT * FROM  " _
            & "NAME WHERE ID = " & variable & ";"

         Print sqls on paper     ' This is just a simple explanation of what I want
```

Comment: On paper must be printed user friendly table, not sql code :)

Comment: Why not you printing report that will filter data as your query from table? If you interested I can give code.

Comment: Yes, I think it will help. Please give me a code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Design a report from table. Use report `Record Source= YourTable`. In form use a `Command Button` to print report. The button will filter report data based on your `variable` and print report through default printer. Here `"[ID]=" & variable` this is `Where Condition` of command. This part will filter data as `variable`.

```
Private Sub Print_Click()
  'DoCmd.OpenReport "YourReportName", acPreview, , "[ID]=" & Me.txtID
  DoCmd.OpenReport "YourReportName", acNormal, , "[ID]=" & variable
End Sub
```

Comment: `acPreview` will preview report and `acNormal` will print report directly.

Answer (score 0):

On a form, any form, put an unbound Text Box. In my example below I have named the text Box 'XportXL'. Create a command button. Enter the name of your query in the unbound control. This will work for any query - just enter its name in the unbound control. ("E:\Peter\Desktop\filename.xlsx" is just the place where I wnat to expert to) put the following code in the OnClick event: 
    Dim MyQuery As String
    MyQuery = Me.XportXL

```
If IsNull(Me.XportXL) Then
    DisplayMessage ("We need something to export.")
    Exit Sub
Else
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, MyQuery, acFormatXLSX, "E:\Peter\Desktop\filename.xlsx", False, "", , acExportQualityScreen
End If
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, this code cannot print excel file... I must open the excel file and click print. It is not solution